# Why does the LinkedIn API return “500 Internal API Server Error” when posting to LinkedIn groups

Tags: api, linkedin-api, http-status-code-500

Why does the LinkedIn API return “500 Internal API Server Error” when posting to LinkedIn groups for specific groups and for some other groups it returns status code '202' with other accounts it works well.

## REQUEST CODE

```
    JsonObject share = new JsonObject();
    String message = "message ";
    share.addProperty("title", message);
    share.addProperty("summary", message);
    String jsonStr = new Gson().toJson(share);

    String shareUrl = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/group/"+account.getAccountId() + "/posts";

    OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, shareUrl);
    request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.addHeader("x-li-format", "json");
    request.addPayload(jsonStr);

    service.signRequest(token, request);
    Response response = request.send();
```

## RESPONSE

We got `"status code 202"` as response for some account
and some account returns,

```
 {
  "errorCode":0,
  "message":"Internal API server error",
  "requestId":"I329W0E239",
  "status":500,
  "timestamp":1418142926436
 }
```

All other accounts works well got `200` as response

Comment: My guess is that you are not a member of the groups for which you are getting the `500` error.  Can you verify this and get back to us?  Try posting directly to these groups.  Are you allowed to do this?